# Windows 8 doesn't play nice when dual booting with Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, multi-boot

I have Windows 7, and Windows 8 on my laptop. I have Windows 7 set as my default, and it asks me each time if I want to boot with 7 or 8. When I boot with Windows 8, then restart my computer, it opens up to the Windows 8 boot screen and sets Windows 8 as my default. How can I stop it from changing my default OS? It's a hassle to change my default each time I want to use Windows 8.

**Note:** This only happens *sometimes*. It usually doesn't change my default OS when I restart, but it sometimes changes when I completely shut my laptop off.

Comment: I wonder if that is by design, you know defaulting to the last OS that you used.... Let me see...

Comment: I can't simulate this. Changed default to Win 7, it's stuck to that.

Comment: Same... Not sure....

Comment: I never have that problem

Comment: I wonder if it's a driver or something then...

Comment: Do you have the latest drivers, firmware, BIOS, etc.?

Comment: yep, latest everything

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed similar behavior on occasions. The reason could be Windows 8's Hibernation settings. Check your Power Options.

[image]

If you have enabled **Hibernation**, then when the system hibernates after the set period and later you power on your system, it would **automatically resume on Windows 8**. This would have higher priority over the boot sequence, as you have *never  actually quit Windows 8*. It is *simply resuming your session*.

Also the new Windows 8 Start/Restart/Hibernate/Resume UI just has the loading logo and no messages indicating the ongoing operation. So its hard to distinguish between restart and resume.

[image]

Comment: I am totally agree  with you @AbhishekGirish. I also have same problem  and I suspect same behavior and on disabling the hibernate option this is never happend again :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `bcdedit`.

**Warning:** *Be sure you type the commands correctly or your machine may become unbootable.*

1. Open a command prompt as administrator.
2. Type `bcdedit /export C:\bcd_old.bak` or something similar to backup the boot configuration data.
3. Type `bcdedit /v` to display the boot configuration data.
4. Copy the identifier for the Windows 7 boot entry (it looks something like 
    `{1e940af5-47c7-11e1-9d16-ceef4a66119e}`).
5. Type `bcdedit /default {identifier of Windows 7 boot entry}`
6. Do this on both Windows 7 and Windows 8.

Now the default should be Windows 7 regardless of which OS was used most recently.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to disable  [Fast Startup](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) for this to be fixed